# python socket file transfer verified with sha256 not working, but only sometimes?

Tags: python, sockets

Client side:

```
def send_file_to_hashed(data, tcpsock):
time.sleep(1)
f = data
flag = 0
i=0
tcpsock.send(hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest())
f.seek(0)
time.sleep(1)
l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE-64)
while True:
    while (l):
        tcpsock.send(hashlib.sha256(l).hexdigest() + l)
        time.sleep(1)
        hashok = tcpsock.recv(6) 
        if  hashok == "HASHOK":
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE-64)
            flag = 1
        if hashok == "BROKEN":
            flag = 0
    if not l:
        time.sleep(1)
        tcpsock.send("DONE")
        break
return (tcpsock,flag)

def upload(filename):
flag = 0
while(flag == 0):
    with open(os.getcwd()+'\\data\\'+ filename +'.csv', 'rU') as UL:
        tuplol = send_file_to_hashed(UL ,send_to_sock(filename +".csv",send_to("upload",TCP_IP,TCP_PORT)))
        (sock,flagn) = tuplol
        flag = flagn
        time.sleep(2)
        sock.close()
```

Server Side:

```
   elif(message == "upload"):
        message = rec_OK(self.sock)
        fis = os.getcwd()+'/data/'+ time.strftime("%H:%M_%d_%m_%Y") + "_" + message
        f = open(fis , 'w')
        latest = open(os.getcwd()+'/data/' + message , 'w')
        time.sleep(1)
        filehash = rec_OK(self.sock)
        print("filehash:" + filehash)
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            rawdata = self.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            log.write("rawdata :" + rawdata + "\n")
            data = rawdata[64:]
            dhash = rawdata[:64]
            log.write("chash: " + dhash + "\n")
            log.write("shash: " + hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest() + "\n")
            if dhash == hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest():
                f.write(data)
                latest.write(data)
                self.sock.send("HASHOK")
                log.write("HASHOK\n" )
                print"HASHOK"
            else:
                self.sock.send("HASHNO")
                print "HASHNO"
                log.write("HASHNO\n")
            if rawdata == "DONE":
                f.close()
                f = open(fis , 'r')

                if (hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest() == filehash): 
                    print "ULDONE"
                    log.write("ULDONE")
                    f.close()
                    latest.close()
                    break
                else:
                    self.sock.send("BROKEN")
                    print hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest()
                    log.write("BROKEN")
                    print filehash
                    print "BROKEN UL"
        f.close()
```

So the data upload is working fine in all tests that i ran from my computer, even worked fine while uploading data over my mobile connection and still sometimes people say it takes a long time and they kill it after a few minutes. the data is there on their computers but not on the server. I don't know what is happening please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: this is unrelated to sha.

Streaming over the network is unpredictable. This line

```
rawdata = self.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

**doesn't guarantee** that you read `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes. You may have read only 1 byte in the worst case scenario. Therefore your server side is completely broken because of the assumption that rawdata contains whole message. It is even worse. If the client sends command and hash fast you may get e.g. `rawdata == 'DONEa2daf78c44(...)` which is a mixed output.

The "hanging" part just follows from that. Trace your code and see what happens when the server receives partial/broken messages ( I already did that in my imagination :P ).

---

Streaming over the network is almost never as easy as calling `sock.send` on one side and `sock.recv` on the other side. You need some buffering/framing protocol. For example you can implement this simple protocol: always interpret first two bytes as the size of incoming message, like this:

**client** (pseudocode)

```
# convert len of msg into two-byte array
# I am assuming the max size of msg is 65536
buf = bytearray([len(msg) & 255, len(msg) >> 8])
sock.sendall(buf)
sock.sendall(msg)
```

**server** (pseudocode)

```
size = to_int(sock.recv(1))
size += to_int(sock.recv(1)) << 8
# You need two calls to recv since recv(2) can return 1 byte.
# (well, you can try recv(2) with `if` here to avoid additional
#     syscall, not sure if worth it)
buffer = bytearray()
while size > 0:
    tmp = sock.recv(size)
    buffer += tmp
    size -= len(tmp)
```

Now you have properly read data in `buffer` variable which you can work with.

**WARNING:** the pseudocode for the server is simplified. For example you need to check for empty `recv()` result everywhere (including where size is calculated). This is the case when the client disconnects.

So unfortunately there's a lot of work in front of you. You have to rewrite whole sending and receving code.

Comment: thanks, your answer made me aware of where I went wrong. I found this https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html for more information on the problem for anybody who sees this and has the same problem